# Managing history records in a database

Tags: java, database, spring, persistence, spring-data

I have a web project that uses a database to store data that is used to generate tasks that would be processed for remote machines to alter that records and store new data. My problem here is that I have to store all that changes on each table but I don't need all these information. For example, a table A could have 5 fields but I only need 2 for historical purposes. Another table B could have 3 and I would have to add another one (date for example). Also, I don't need changes during daily task generation, only the most recent one.

Which is the best way to maintain a change history? Someone told me that a good idea is having two tables, the A (B) table and another one called A_history (B_history) with the needed fields. This is actually what I'm doing, using triggers to insert into history tables but I don't feel comfortable with this approach. My project uses Spring (Spring-data, Hibernate and JPA) and if I change the DB (currently MySQL) I'd have to migrate triggers. Is there a good way to manage history records? Tables could be generated with Hibernate/JPA annotations.

If I maintain the two tables approach, can I add a method to the repository to fetch rows from current table and history table at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this pourpose there is a special [Hibernate Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers) project. See official documentation [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html). Just configure it, annotate necessary properties with @Audited annotation and that's all. No need for DB triggers.

One pitfall: if you want to have a record for each delete operation then you need to use `Session.delete(entity)` way instead of HQL "delete ...".

**EDIT.** Also take a look into [native auditing support](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html#jpa.auditing) of spring data jpa.

Comment: Hibernate Envers is exactly what I need (at least I think so...). Just one question. Is is compatible with Spring Data (JPA). I'm using repositories to connect with my DB and I don't want to rewrite too much to add Envers.

Comment: I am do not have such kind of experiance: Spring Data JPA + Hibernate Envers. Bu I am sure that it must work fine. As I mentioned earlier, do not use update / delete HQL queries if you want capture their changes in corresponding audit table (in a case of JpaRepository do not use methods like `deleteInBatch(Iterable<T> entities)` and `deleteAllInBatch()`)

Comment: there are some problems with Hibernate envers that not solved yet, for example, if you are using Formula in your domain model it can not audit the field that has Formula, the issue is open in Hibernate Jira https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11785

Answer (score 1):

I am not a database expert. What I have seen them do boils down to a few ways of approach.

1) They add a trigger to the transactional table that copies inserts and updates to a history table but not deletes. This means any queries that need to include history can be done from the history table since all the current info is there too.

- a) They can tag each entry in the history table with time and date and
  keep track of all the states of the original records.
- b) They can only
  keep track of the current state of the original record and then it
  settles when the original is deleted.

2) They have a periodic task that goes around and copies data marked as deletable into the history table. It then deletes the data from the transactional table. Any queries in the transactional table have to make sure to ignore the deletable rows. Any queries that need history have to search both tables and merge the results.

3) If the volume of data isn't too large, they just leave everything in one table and mark some entries as historical. Queries have to ignore historical rows. Queries that include history are easy. This may slow down database access as the table grows to include many unused rows but that can sometimes be ameliorated by clever use of indexes.